# jQuery not auto updating on select

Tags: jquery, html

Is there any reason the following jquery wouldn't work when the user selects something from the drop down. (It is suppose to auto update)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#state").change(function () {
                this.form.submit();
})
});
</script>


  <form action="avsafety.asp" method="get">



     <p>State:<br/>
      <select id="state" name="state">
        <option label="ACT" value="ACT" <%if request.querystring("state") = "ACT" then response.write("selected") %>>ACT</option>
        <option label="NSW" value="NSW" <%if request.querystring("state") = "NSW" then response.write("selected") %>>NSW</option>
        <option label="QLD" value="QLD" <%if request.querystring("state") = "QLD" then response.write("selected") %>>QLD</option>
        <option label="VIC" value="VIC" <%if request.querystring("state") = "VIC" then response.write("selected") %>>VIC</option>
        <option label="SA" value="SA"   <%if request.querystring("state") = "SA" then response.write("selected") %>>SA</option>
        <option label="TAS" value="TAS" <%if request.querystring("state") = "TAS" then response.write("selected") %>>TAS</option>
        <option label="WA" value="WA"   <%if request.querystring("state") = "WA" then response.write("selected") %>>WA</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>

  </form>
```

Comment: You might be missing a `;` at the end of `.change(function(){});`

Comment: Should work fine, if submitting the form and reloading the page each time a new option is selected is what you're trying to do? Semicolons are "optional", but it's good practice to use them.

Comment: What's it doing? What errors do you get?

Comment: It works a few times and then it stops working. It'll stop automatically updating whenever the TAS option is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your options are changed dynamically

give it a try with

```
     $(document).ready(function() {

              $(document).on("change","select#state",function(e){
                             $("form").submit();
                               });

     });
```

Comment: How would I integrate that? Relatively new to jquery. Thanks.

Comment: instead of $("state").change(function(){}); also as other poster say submit form not the select

Answer (score 0):

`this` in the context of the function you are using is pointing to the `select#state`. In other words, you cannot send a form because there is no form inside the select. Instead change your code to something like this:

```
$("#state").change(function () {
         $("form").submit();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#state").find("option:selected").change(function(){});`